# Mock pandas read_csv using pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have a python function that takes a BigQuery bucket name & file path as inputs and does the following:

- Check if the bucket it exists
- Check if the file is in the bucket
- Read the file into a dataframe and return the dataframe

The function looks something like this:

```
def function_to_test(client, bucket_name, delimiter, full_path=None, header=None):
    try:
        bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
        assert bucket is not None
    except (gcp_exceptions.GoogleCloudError, AssertionError) as ex:
        raise AirflowFailException(f"Failed to access bucket: {bucket_name}") from ex

    try:
        blob = bucket.get_blob(full_path)
        assert blob is not None
        if blob.size == 0:
            print(f'File is empty')
            return None
        df = pd.read_csv(f"gs://{bucket_name}/{full_path}", sep=delimiter, dtype='str', header=header)
        return df
    except(gcp_exceptions.GoogleCloudError, AssertionError) as ex:
        raise AirflowFailException(f"Failed to retrieve blob from bucket: {bucket_name}") from ex
```

I am trying to write pytest tests for this function and so far I have the following:

```
def test_func(mocker, generic_df):
    bucket_name = 'test_bucket'
    full_path = 'test_path'
    mock_client = mocker.patch('google.cloud.storage.Client', autospec=True)
    mock_bucket = mock_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    actual_df =  function_to_test(client=mock_client,bucket_name=bucket_name, delimiter=',', full_path=full_path, header=0)
```

Currently, the above mocking of the bucket is sufficient to pass the bucket requirements in the function.

However, I am unable to figure out how to mock the `read_csv` functionality and as such, the dataframe creation is failing.

Is there a way I can mock this function so that the dataframe is mocked too?

Comment: In a pytest fixture you could yield a test file (csv) and clean it up afterwards. We use this pattern regularly at my firm. See the docs on this topic https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#teardown-cleanup-aka-fixture-finalization

Comment: I'm not sure how that would help as the path for the df, `gs://{bucket_name}/{full_path}` is not passed through from the test. Unless I am misunderstanding how you are using yield.